# Hp Data Protector backup destination command line

Tags: data-protector

I'm using Hp DP ver. A.06.11 on HP-UX with 24 slots tape library.

On DP Gui, I'm able to specify backup destination. Is it possible to do it from the command line?

When I type the command

```
/opt/omni/bin/omnib -datalist "DAILY BACKUP" -mode full -load high
```

it will always use slot no. 21 but I have different tape for each day.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is that the tape in slot 21 is in some tape pool (probably something like "Default LTO"). That pool is marked as "Appendable", which means that Data Protector will write to that tape until it is full. Then it will move on to the next-best tape.

The algorithm for choosing the "best" tape is: the tape with the fewest overwrites, and if there's a tie, the tape that was initialised first. If a tape isn't in the library and the pool is not marked as "Strict Allocation", then Data Protector will skip that tape.

A few thoughts:

- Usually people want backups written across different tapes each day  because they want to take tapes offsite -- which is a good idea. So take the tape out, and Data Protector will use another tape.
- You could change the pool to being Non-appendable, or Appendable for Incrementals Only.
- You could se the omnimm -move_medium command to take that tape out of the pool that it is in, and put it another. This will mean that that tape is not used for backup any more.

I think you also should be aware that Data Protector 6.1 went out of support many, many years ago, and that you are putting your organisation's backups at risk by continuing to use it. If you are on a support contract, it's a free upgrade to version 9. Then you would be able to ask the HP response centre these kinds of questions.

The sensible upgrade path would be to install Data Protector 9 on a Linux virtual machine to be the new cell manager, and then make this HP-UX box a client of that new cell. I've written about how to do this (and migrate backup history to it) in my book
http://store.data-protector.net/products/migrating-cloning-and-obsoleting-hp-data-protector-cell-managers